# Display Firebase images into Array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to display my images from Firebase into my collection view. I don't know how to get the correct node from Firebase to access the images branch. Some users will have up to 5 images however some users will not have an images branch at all. Here is my firebase data structure.

[image]

```
var imagesArray: [String] = []

public func numberOfItems(in pagerView: FSPagerView) -> Int {
    return imagesArray.count
}

public func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, cellForItemAt index: Int) -> FSPagerViewCell {
    let cell = pagerView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)

    return cell
}

struct Users {
     var email: String!
     var uid: String!
     var ref: DatabaseReference!
     var location: String?
     var photoURL: String!
     var biography: String?
     var key: String?
     var name: String!
     var phoneNumber: NSNumber? 
     var password: String!
}
```

Comment: Your images are in firebase storage while the link url is in firebase database right?

Comment: the photoURL won't be displayed in the collectionView, only the images from the images branch

Comment: Did you store the image in firebaseStorage ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do.

1. Get Reference to image node

> ```
>     dbImageRef = Database.database().child("Users")
> .child("Images")
> .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
>
>       let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary 
>        for image in value{
>
>
>       // add the image links in an image array here
>        }
>     }
> ```

2. Use a library such as Kingfisher to download and display the images.

Comment: It should be .child("Users").child(<Id>).child("Images")

Comment: I get this error Cannot convert value of type 'DataSnapshot' to type 'NSDictionary' in coercion on the fifth line of let value = snapshot

Comment: Sorry let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary. Post editied

Comment: self.imagesArray.append(image) : Cannot convert value of type '(key: Any, value: Any)' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: You need to type case your image url to type String and note that here in your case image is NSDictionary

Answer (score 0):

1) take one array.

```
var arrImages: [[String: String]] = []
```

2) Then use this function to reach the images node.

```
Database.database().child("Users").child(<id>).child("Images").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let images = users.value as? Dictionary
                        self.arrImages.append(images)
                    }

                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }else{
                print("No Images")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am gettin an error on self.arrImages.append(image). 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type 'String'. when I add as! String I also get a crash